# How apply geoserver sld vendor options for label placement on openlayers WFS

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, sld

I have defined SLD style on geoserver with following options:

```
        <VendorOption name="spaceAround">2</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.3</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
```

I have many labels and I don't want overlaping on small zoom. When I apply sld style on layer and preview it on geoserver, it is working in desired way.
However, I want use that style on WFS layer, and in application labels are not formatted in same way as on geoserver.
I'm guessing it's because styleMap ignores it for some reason.
So my question is, does OpenLayers have some property for label positioning, or can I with some other vendor options or somehow else achieve same result using geoserver sld style.

Answer (score 1):

Vendor Options are (as the name suggests) implementation specific so it is no surprise that OpenLayers doesn't support the same ones as GeoServer does.

Label placement is a hard problem (and takes a lot of time and memory) to do well  as you have to extract the labels from each layer as they are rendered and then place them at the end of rendering. So I suspect that OpenLayers will never catch up with GeoServer in labelling.

The obvious answer is to request your layer as a WMS layer and allow GeoServer to handle the styling for you. If you are using a WFS from some other source then you could cascade it through GeoServer as a vector source and the style it in to a WMS layer.